# how to attach an event receiver to a custom list in sharepoint?

Tags: c#, sharepoint

What are the steps required in attaching an event receiver to a custom list in sharepoint?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done in at least two different ways:

1. Create a feature that upon feature activation you have the proper code to attach to a specific list ([use this URL](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointdevelopment/thread/6ca86d4f-5c8c-4e48-8940-811799260e36) for some help)
2. Or you could have a console application that will have code to attach to a specific list (again using the same code as in the URL mentioned above)

For further help [go here](http://www.davehunter.co.uk/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=69).

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to attach EventReceivers to lists, ContentTypes or sites. Take a look at [Brian Wilson's blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/brianwilson/archive/2007/03/18/event-handlers-part-3-register-event-handlers-plus-free-site-settings-manage-event-handlers-add-on.aspx) about this topic and describes several ways to do this.

He also developed a SharePoint Feature which deploys a configuration page where you can attach and delete EventReceivers over an UI.

Answer (score 0):

you may go to element file and edit the tag Receivers, change the value of the attribut ListUrl to whatever is your URL for instance if your list is called Customers, insert `<Receivers ListUrl="Lists/Customers">`
 Try this and good luck

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is replace the following line in Elements.xml:

```
<Receivers ListTemplateId="*number*">
```

with

```
<Receivers ListUrl="Lists/*your list name*">
```

**Note** that "Url" is written with only the first character capitalized